# Accessing a LUKS encrypted ext4 HDD from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, encryption, ext3

I have a LUKS encrypted external hard-drive with ext4 filesystem and I recently started using Windows 10 as my main OS.
I tried to gain access to this external HDD from Win10 via various applications (Ext2Fsd, Ext2Read, Paragon and others) with no success due to the LUKS encryption.

Is there any way to access a LUKS protected ext4 from Win10?

Edit: If it wasn't clear, I do know the password.

Comment: What do you mean by "password protected ext3"? My understanding is that encryption of the filesystem was added for ext4.

Comment: I assume he's talking about a dm-crypt/LUKS encrypted partition.

Comment: @davidgo I'm sorry, apparently it's ext4. Edited original post. According to Gparted it's luks encryption.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  Note that LUKS has nothing to do with Ext4 - LUKS encrypts a partition and exposes it as a block device regardless of the filesystem on it.  Thus to run it under Windows you need something to mount the LUKS partition, then a tool to read EXT4.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to access password protected ext3 from Win10?

No, any encrypted file system to be accessible needs:

1. an OS that supports said file system natively
2. the password

Windows software for reading ext file systems is limited, does not support encryption and is generally unreliable even with non-encrypted files.